# Installing Direct Debit UK and Smart Debit extensions for civi 4.6

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, contribution-page, recurring-contributions

Has anybody installed the Direct Debit UK and Smart Debit extensions for Civi 4.6 (specifically) 4.6.10?

I've searched but can't find a definitive answer regarding compatability.

And, do these extensions work with webforms?

I know I could fire in, install and find out; but wanted to see if I could learn from other people's experience.

Cheers!

Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are the extension maintainers so hopefully can help with any questions. Yes, they're actively used and installed however they're not explicitly designed to work with webform.

We've just released a 4.6 ready version of the extensions that needed it, the rest are 4.6 compatible already and should indicate so.

Let us know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hi Parvez,

I've installed both extensions and am now trying to configure them.

I've updated the Organisation Name and Address fields via the Direct Debit Settings Screen. The organisation doesn't have a 4th line to the address. Can this line just be deleted via PHP my admin?

Similarly the Direct Debit Settings show fields for
api_contact_key payerReference 
api_contact_val_regex
api_contact_val_regex_index

Where should I find the values to enter into these fields?

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Hi Craig, You can leave the 4th line of address as the default value. The address details are for information purpose only and are not sent via API to smart debit when processing payments. Also api_contact_val_regex, api_contact_val_regex_index can be left blank as the values are dynamically set (with the Payer Reference value)