# A required State field in a contribution page is not populating. What can I do?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

I’ve just installed the UK Direct Debit extension (with the smart debit extension) for a site using civicrm 4.6.10.

I’m trying to configure a membership contribution page using the new payment processor and have a problem when using the live page.

https://crm.reach.org.uk/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=16

In the billing address section both country and state are listed as required fields, but the state field fails to populate after the country is selected.

The site is set so that UK is the default country, I’ve tried to run the page with and without the default set, and the issue with the state field remains.

On the existing membership contribution pages for the site (using paypal as payment processor) the state drop down works fine.

On inspecting the element for JS I find this error message- “Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.”

Has anybody else encountered this issue? Can you direct me to the file that controls the layout of the direcr debit billing template? Can I edit this without affecting other contribution pages on the site?

Or is there a simple way to remove the state field from the template or make it not required?

Comment: Which extension exactly are you using? Is it marked as compatible with 4.6?

Comment: Hi Coleman

I'm using uk direct debit

https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.ukdirectdebit

and Smart Debit Payment Processor
https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.smartdebitdd

I had an answer on here in November from parvez saying it was compatible with 4.6

http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/installing-direct-debit-uk-and-smart-debit-extensions-for-civi-4-6

Comment: Have just emailed them directly to ask if they've had this issue before.

Comment: If you find out the answer, post it here :)

Comment: Was planning to. Once I find time to chase it up ;)